# Is it mutar to grab drinks with coworkers

Tags: gentiles, liquor-beer, parnassah-livelihood

In [Shulchan Aruch Yoreh Deah 114:1](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9146&st=&pgnum=11&hilite=) it states that it is prohibited to drink certain (alcoholic) drinks together with a non-Jew due to the Issur of "Chasnus".  Would this issue apply in a case where a Jew wants to grab drinks (at a local bar?) with co-workers during a happy hour?  Would there be an additional Kulah/leniency if the point of such a meeting would be for team-building purposes?

Comment: @Modern-Yesheevish try adding a specific issue as the focus of your question. See http://www.workplacehalacha.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/Chapter-14-Drinking-with-non-Jews1.pdf and https://www.torahmusings.com/2017/12/holiday-parties-2/ for possible issues and sources, choose a source and say "based on this _____, is there an issue of _______ in grabbing drinks during happy hour?

Comment: @רבותמחשבות added source.

Comment: @Modern-Yesheevish it's a bit better, but which halacha in SA are you referring to, and what does it say, and what is the issue you want us to address?  BTW, I'm not trying to be hard, just to clear things up a little (same as people did to me when I started here 2 months ago).  By all means it's a good question.

Comment: @רבותמחשבות updated with se'if and mishum chasnus

Comment: @Modern-Yesheevish is this better?  if not, just roll back the edit.  I voted to reopen this question.

Comment: Modern-Yesheevish, pay attention to @רבותמחשבות 's advice and his example. They are useful lessons to learn for crafting a good post around here.

Comment: @DoubleAA I had a good Rebbi lol https://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/89053/revisions

Comment: @רבותמחשבות bnei adam ;), very good and thank you. Will keep in mind.